# django formset attribute editing

Tags: django, forms, django-forms

Currently looking at: http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/

I'm currently trying to create a simple product form, where the author/ user creating the product is added later. My code is as follows:

```
ProductFormSet = modelformset_factory(Product, exclude=('pub_date', 'author')) #handle categories separately/ via JSON feed

if request.method == 'POST':
    formset = ProductFormSet(request.POST, request.FILES)

    if formset.is_valid():
        new = formset.save(commit=False)
        new.author = request.user
        new.save()
        return HttpResponse("DONE!!")
```

However I get an attribute error as 'new' seems to be returned as an empty list rather than an instance of the new form object. Where am I going wrong??

Many thanks,

Adam

Comment: basically taking code from django docs.. "form = PartialAuthorForm(request.POST)
author = form.save(commit=False)
author.title = 'Mr'
author.save()"
but this doesn't seem to work??

Comment: Don't add comments to your own post - edit it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to be confusing forms and formsets.

A form is for editing a single instance, and `form.save()` (in the case of a model form) returns the saved instance.

A formset is for editing multiple instances. `formset.save()` returns the list of instances that were saved. Obviously, the list itself doesn't have an `author` attribute - it's each instance within that list that does. So you'd need to loop through the list and set `author` on each item.